# Buscador en vivo, modificación

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Buenas tengo un buscador en vivo con una tabla y javascript. Pero ahora necesito modificar este JavaScript para que busque en relación a este `div`

**MODIFICO TRAS LA RESPUESTA** - Me sigue sin funcionar!

**El buscador**

```
   <div class="col-6">
     <input type="text" name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" placeholder="Busca tu prueba.." title="Type in a name">
    </div>
```

**Los datos que arroja**

```
       <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="row datos">
              <?php
                 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM analisis");
                 foreach ($results as $tipos){

                ?>
                <div class="col-4 center ">
                  <div class="col-12 fondoPruebas3450">
                    <div class="row ">
                      <div class="col-8">
                        <h4><?php echo $tipos['strnombre'] ?></h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-4">
                        <h3><?php echo $tipos['strprecio'] ?>€</h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="divider902"></div>
                    <div class="txtPruebas22 center"><?php echo $tipos['strconocido'] ?></div>

                    <div class="">
                      <?php
                        if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 0) echo "<img src='images/svg/drop.svg' alt='' class='im-card'> Muestra de sangre";
                        if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 1) echo "<img src='images/svg/orina.svg' alt='' class='im-card'> Muestra de orina";
                        if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 2) echo "<img src='images/svg/orinsan.svg' alt='' class='im-card'> Muestra de Sangre y Orina";
                        if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 3) echo "<img src='images/svg/pelo.svg' alt='' class='im-card'> Muestra de pelo";
                        if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 4) echo "<img src='images/svg/baston.svg' alt='' class='im-card'>Muestra Exudada";
                        if ($tipos['sangreorina'] == 5) echo "<img src='images/svg/baston.svg' alt='' class='im-card'>Muestra Exudada y de sangre";
                                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                      <?php if ($tipos['strprecio'] == 0) {
                        echo "<div class=\"ayuno\"><i class=\"fas fa-info-circle\"></i> No es necesario ayuno</div>";
                        }else {
                        echo "<div class=\"ayuno\"><i class=\"fas fa-info-circle\"></i> Es necesario ayuno</div>";
                        }
                      ?>
                    </div>

                <a href="" class="btnAddCarro">Añadir al carrito</a>
                <a href="" class="btnMasInfo">Ver información prueba</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**El javascript**

```
$('#txtSearch').on('keyup',(e)=>{
      let contenedor = $('#contenedor');
      let search = $('#txtSearch').val();
      contenedor.children('.row.datos').each((i,e)=>{
       if($(e)[0].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())){
       $(e).css("display","")
       }else{
       $(e).css("display","none")
       }
      })
    })
```

Comment: Cuál es el div con el que funciona actualmente?

Comment: ahora no esta funcionando con ninguno, quiero que busque según el div que tiene el PHP `strnombre`. he realizado pruebas pero no consigo nada, gracias!

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Donde están estos elementos `input = document.getElementById("myInput");` y `table = document.getElementById("myTable");`No los veo en el HTML. Tampoco es claro qué es lo que quieres hacer. El HTML que muestras no tiene ninguna relación con el Javascript que muestras.

Comment: hola, ese javascript lo tenia antes para realizar busquedas en vivo sobre una tabla, entonces por cada letra que escribia en el buscador me mostraba en la tabla los resultados que coincidian. Pero ahora no tengo estos datos en una tabla, de ahí que digo que quiero hacer lo mismo que tenia pero con el contido del `col-3`

Answer (score 1):

Ya que tu pregunta no es muy clara, supongo que ahora en vez de utilizar una tabla utilizas un contenedor con varios divs y que quieres filtrar a traves de ellos por lo que te dejo este ejemplo.

```js
$('#txtSearch').on('keyup',(e)=>{
let contenedor = $('#contenedor');
let search = $('#txtSearch').val();
contenedor.children('.row.datos').each((i,e)=>{
 if($(e)[0].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())){
 $(e).css("display","")
 }else{
 $(e).css("display","none")
 }
})
})
```

```css
.datos{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border:1pt solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label for="txtSearch">Buscar:</label><input type="text" name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" class="form-control">
<br>
<div id="contenedor" class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Nombre</h4>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Edad</h4>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Dinero</h4>
    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row datos">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Alejandra</h4>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>18</h4>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>$600</h4>
    
  </div>
</div>
<!--fila 2-->
<div class="row datos">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Ana</h4>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>21</h4>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>$3200</h4>
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Hola gracias, si entendiste aun que no me explicara bien, voy a modificar la pregunta con tu respuesta ya que no me funciona bien, gracias!